# How to host same contract with 2 different configurations as 2 services in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I've developed a contract for WCF. It has a database connection. So I like to connect with 2 different databases with 2 different services. So how can I host that contract with 2 different configurations (like database name, username, password)  as 2 services in 2 different addresses?

For Example
I have a contract called DataHandler.
Now I have to register them as 2 services on a system,
First service can access databse1 and second service can access database2

I can't give database1 & database2 as a parameter from client application.
So how to solve this problem?
Can I give any parameter to service contract from hosting server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one service with single endpoint and single configuration and deploy this service to two different applications each providing correct configuration. It seems like a strange solution but it is the simplest one and in many scenarios also the correct one. It also provides the best separation between two configurations.

Comment: But I'm not feeling comfortable about exposing database name, database username, database password to client side

Comment: You will not expose it to client side - those applications hosting the service and providing the configuration are server side.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
Bt Sorry, I couldn't get you. Can you explain little bit?
How to pass configurations from servers to service?

Comment: You will have connection string in your configuration file (or any other configuration you need) and your service will simply use it. Because each service deployment will be in separate application you will have only one such set of configuration values - there will be no decision logic in your service.